# Different JRE for Runtime and Compiling in Grails STS environment

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am working on migrating my grails app from Java 6 to Java 7.  In order to do this, the plan is to continue to compile in Java 6 and change the runtime environment to Java 7.  This will get migrated up through the environments.  After that is complete the build server we have will get upgraded to Java 7 so things start compiling in Java 7.

The issue I am having is replicating an environment on my local machine to work on issues such as [Incompatible Class Change Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826967/geb-incompatibleclasschangeerror).  I have set my Build Path to point to the Java 6 JDK as well as changed 
Preferences -> Java -> Compiler to 1.6 compliance 
as well as changed 
Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs to use the Java 6 JDK.

When I call `System.getProperty("java.class.version")` I would expect to receive 50.0 indicating the class files were compiled with Java 6.  However, I receive 51.0 indicating it is compiling in Java 7.

What else is there that I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a cue from an unrelated error with classpaths [classpath container for Grails in STS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057844/classpath-container-for-grails-in-sts)  I deleted .ivy2 and .grails folders.  Somehow the previously compiled files were stale despite cleaning.  I do have multiple workspaces for the same project (different branches) which may be using the same .ivy2 and .grails folders which very likely caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project -> Properties -> Java Compiler and uncheck the Enable project specific settings.

If this doesn't works go to [your grails workspace path]/.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core.launches and then edit the files that contain the java path to spot the correct one

Comment: The issue was that some .grails files were not being cleaned up.  Removing these fixed the problem.